# Vector of indexed containers in generic struct

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to use a vector of indexed containers, e.i. any type that implements `std::ops::Index`, but I can't find a solution to assigning the type for `type Output` in the implementation section.

From what I know it should look something like this:

```rust
pub struct Holder<C: Index<usize> + ExactSizeIterator> {  
    containers: Vec<C>
}

impl<C: Index<usize>, T> Index<usize> for Holder<C> {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

But this obviously ends up with

> the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
> unconstrained type parameter rustc(E0207)

(For clarification, the error points to the `T` in `impl<C: Index<usize>, T>`)

However I do not know of a way of adding another generic type to the definition of `Holder` that wouldn't just be an unused field.

The purpose of `Holder` is to contain other containers that are indexable and the index function of `Holder` should return an item from one of said containers.

Let me know if there anything is missing from the post. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to remove `T` entirely and deduce the `Output` type from `C` directly:

```
impl<C: Index<usize> + ExactSizeIterator> Index<usize> for Holder<C> {
    type Output = C::Output; // <--------

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think about that!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the associated type defined by your generic parameter like this:

```rust
    type Output = C::Output;
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8ed54c372015555c6d44df282a68d75c)